# How to approach a HR to ask for an internship at a company where my father is working?

Tags: human-resources, email

I am keen to ask for a summer internship at a MNC company that my father has been working. Some info: My dad is working as a workman and therefore has barely interacted with any upper managerial roles, but still, he has the HR email address. How would I go about writing an email asking for any internship roles at the company?

Comment: Is an internship position being offered?

Comment: @sf02 Nope, from the company website, but still I would want to try to ask if there is any

Comment: If your father has a good relationship with his supervisor (translation in this case: anything that is not a bad relationship), then he could perhaps ask the supervisor if there is another person who would be better to "ask for advice about applying", besides HR. Very often, having a chance to speak with, or even just email, the hiring manager prior to submitting the application helps get the interview.

Comment: Is the HR email address you're contacting publicly available (anyone interested in an internship could find it), or did you get a specific contact from your father?

Comment: @NuclearHoagie I had a specific contact from my father

Comment: @Elssie, in that case, if you want, can start with "Dear XXX [etc] I got your contact from XXX who is my father and works for XXX group ...", which gives a natural reason for stating the same fact.

Comment: What country? What is the local practice in this country? I read a news story where one of the managers in the EU bureaucracy was complaining that every swede in his team always asked him for internships for the children - as this is the norm there, whereas in other countries it is unthinkable nepotism.

Answer (score 12):

I'd just type up the email as usual and then, at the bottom, say something like:

> In the interests of full transparency, my father works at [insert company name] as a [insert job title]

Add that and then I'd say send the email!

Comment: @FrankHopkins - good catch! If you want to edit my post you'll prob get +2 points for making that edit! I mean, I can do it, too, but I don't want to rob you of +2 points haha

Comment: I typically don't like editing other people's answers as I consider them "theirs" and I also don't care about reputation points, but thanks I guess.

Answer (score 6):

Do mention that your father works there and make it a selling point. Something like:

> My father has been one of your employees for x years, I have seen during this time his commitment and honor when talking about his role in your company. I do think that I share your company's values as my father does and I would like to play a part in it.

Not necessarily literally, just to give you an idea that it is a positive point in your application. The more years your father has worked there the better I would also add.

At the same time like someone else said, if there is a policy against it you will be informed and you would have avoided wasting time in potential interviews and similar.

Do not hide this information in any case, if you are spotted later, it will reflect badly on you and your father. It is not worth the while.

For the application format google "unsolicited internship application" and then work around the idea I mentioned above.

Comment: _"I have seen during this time his commitment and honor when talking about his role in your company. I do think that I share your company's values as my father does and I would like to play a part in it."_. This sounds very phony to me; some people don't like to be sweet-talked like that, so it might back-fire.

Answer (score 3):

#### Ask your dad to ask his manager about the possibility of an internship.

After I graduated from university and spent a few years looking for work with no success, I asked a relative of mine if it would be possible to do an unpaid internship with the company they were working for, just to have *something* to put on my resume. They talked to their boss, their boss talked to HR, and eventually I got an offer of a short-term paid contract (since unpaid internships were only legal in my location if you were a university student who was taking the internship as a part of your studies).

Granted, my relative was a team lead who had been working there for about a decade at that point, but if your dad has been there for some time, has a reputation as a solid worker, and is willing to vouch for your character, this approach might work for you as well.

It's also possible that your dad's boss might tell your dad to tell you to follow a particular process (e.g. sending your resume to a particular person); in that case, you should follow the process you were instructed to follow.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to the other answer, I wouldn't mention it.

You are an adult, and your own person. Your relationship to the company is separate from your fathers relationship to the company.

There is no conflict of interest risk.

Just apply like you usually would have.

Comment: Why not use a potential resource if you have it?

Comment: If it was a small company I'd tend to agree. But this is a MNC. They probably have equal opportunity policies that prohibit nepotism.

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be a professional one.

Things to approach:

- your education that fits a possible position in that company
- your interest in that particular domain/to see how it is in practice
- your interest in the actual company (tell them what you find interesting/attractive about them)

The fact that your father works there ca be added as a foot-note, as an observation. In most cases it can be seen as something good, but you don't want to focus on that. It may be interpreted in a bad manner if you do.

Comment: Your answer seems to end prematurely

Comment: Indeed; I fixed it.